# nmea_navsat_driver not sending any data (ublox m8p)

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to use the nmea_navsat_driver PKG to get GPS-Data from a ublox C94-M8P-3 Receiver. When running "rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_serial_driver _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=9600 " No data is published on the "/fix" topic. The nmea_serial_driver also does not print any output. I made sure my user is in the dialout group. And when using ucenter from ublox i can see that the GPS-Receiver is working.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260089/nmea_navsat_driver-not-sending-any-data-(ublox-m8p)/) by [blasalat](https://answers.ros.org/users/18941/blasalat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

are you sure, that the ublox gps sends clear ascii nmea data?

I expect ublox uses an own binary data format and navsat cannot decode it.

You can verify it very easily:

Use minicom and connect to your device (9600 8N1).
Now you should see "clear text" human readable strings with NMEA sentences from your gps.

If not, you are in pain and you need to find an option to switch to ublox format (unkown to me).

Good luck

Cheers
Christian

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1